# How to change the breaks in the legend of my t_map object

Tags: r, legend, spatial, tmap, legend-properties

I have created a map in tmap of all London Green space access points, with the amount of crimes counted in close proximity of the access point showing on the map via colour. However, with the final output as shown in this image.

map of green space access points and criminal activity

[image]

the breaks between each colour change in the classifier do not show the variation I am looking to achieve (breaks currently being (1, 501, 1001, 15001, 2000). I instead wanted to change these breaks to (1, 100, 500, 1000, 2000). Is there anyway I can do this as I have looked online but have found no answers. The code for the map output is bellow:

```
tm_shape(London_Ward_shp) + 
   tm_fill(palette = "grey") + 
   tm_borders(alpha=.3, col = "white") + 
   tm_shape(London_GS_Access_Points_Public) + 
   tm_bubbles(size = 0.05, col = "crime_2020", style = "pretty", scale = 1) + 
   tm_layout(main.title= "2020 Crime Levels near Public Park/Garden Access Points in London", 
             main.title.fontface = 1, fontfamily = "Helvetica", 
             legend.outside = TRUE, legend.position = c("right", "bottom"), 
             legend.title.size = 1, legend.title.fontface = 1, frame = FALSE)
```

a big thank you in advance!

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust the `style` parameter and add the`breaks` parameter in your `tm_bubbles()` call:

`tm_bubbles(size = 0.05, col = "crime_2020", style = "fixed", scale = 1, breaks = c(1, 100, 500, 1000, 2000)`)